# Is there a faster alternative to Map<Int,Int> in Haxe when transpiling to php

Tags: optimization, haxe

Haxe

```
public var bonus:Map<Int,Int>;

if (bonus.exists(id))
    score += bonus.get(id);
```

Compiles to the following php

```
if($bonus->exists($id))
    $score += $bonus->get($id);
```

Ideally I'd like haxe to generate

```
if(isset($bonus[$id]))
    $score += $bonus[$id];
```

I suspect it would be possible using dynamic however I'd like to avoid using dynamic as it is not recommended.  Exists is unnecessary in php but will not compile for our as3 target.  Current profiling shows exists (50% of execution time) and get (30%) are quite expensive.  I'd hope that it would be possible to either use the built in array type or at least inline the exists and get calls.  Can anyone tell me how or recommend a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP's isset(), you may simply compare the variable with null, ie. "myVar != null".

```
if(bonus[id] != null)
    score += bonus[id];
```

or with ternary operator

```
score += (bonus[id] != null) ?: bonus[id];
```

Sidenote:

I believe, you could also try a PHP `in_array()` solution by using `Lambda.has(arrayOrMap, "key");`. But i don't know exactly if Lambda.has works on Maps.

But still, the `!=` would be faster than a call to `in_array()`.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to check if id is in the Map bonus, not if id is non null.  I will give Lambda a try.

Comment: Ok, got it wrong. What about ArrayAccess to the Map, like: bonus[id] - updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That works great, exists is gone now.   get(id) != null wouldn't work on as3 for me, but this appears to work correctly on both my targets.  Thanks a lot.